# When is the limit of a sequence over $n$ the limit of the differences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Under what conditions on the sequence $a_n$ does
$$
\lim_{n→∞} \frac{a_n}n = \lim_{n→∞} (a_{n+1} − a_n )
$$
hold?

Comment: Certainly when the sequence converges.   Otherwise, beats me.

Comment: @Randall: also if $a_n = Cn+D$, for instance.

Comment: also if $a_n = C\ln(n) + D$

Comment: Generalizes to $a_n = O(n)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the second limit exists (finite or infinite), then also the first one exists and the two limits are equal. It is a particular case of the [Cesaro-Stolz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I needed :-)